# Alternative to plain chocolate in pot de creme

Tags: chocolate, dessert, cream

Pot de creme, a semi-set dessert consisting of double cream, sugar and chocolate, is traditionally made with dark, bitter chocolate. I have one family member who hates dark chocolate, but I'd like to make this with milk chocolate for them instead.

To my palate, using cream plus milk chocolate will make this quite sickly and overpowering. Is there any way to get the same consistency and texture as with the dark chocolate while using milk chocolate without it being too rich?

Comment: Milk chocolate is just chocolate plus, well, milk, so adding cream makes dark chocolate into milk chocolate.

Comment: @GdD And sugar, right?

Comment: Dark chocolate has sugar @dbmag9, usually plenty of it.

Comment: Where I live (UK) there's a recent variety from Cadbury known as darkmilk. That might work well here, but it would be an experiment (hence not an answer). As the name suggests it's got less milk and more flavour than normal milk chocolate.

Comment: @GdD, "Milk chocolate is just chocolate plus ....". I know that. You know that. Family member is convinced dark chocolate is the spawn of the devil, even in small amounts. No amount of rationalising will persuade them otherwise !

Comment: @GdD Sure, but as far as I'm aware milk chocolate generally has much more sugar than dark, which is relevant if the OP wanted to replicate the taste of milk chocolate while using dark.

Comment: @Greybeard If there are no health issues and the preference is totally arbitrary then I'd just lie.

Comment: Sadly @dbmag9 I'm not a convincing fibber. However I will try a deflection technique based on the recipe below "I know you hate dark chocolate, but this recipe is a milk chocolate version" and hope the question is not asked as to what is actually in it !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Food and Wine](https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/milk-chocolate-pots-de-creme) says to use mostly milk chocolate, with a little dark chocolate for balance.

Comment: I'm going with this as I can sell it "I found a milk chocolate version just for you". I'm hoping no penetrating questions are asked as to ingredients !!